how to resolve this secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using ES256
i am creating a jwt token with private key but receiving this error secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using ES256
i created private key by using this command on ubuntu 22.04, nodejs v12.22.9
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 -out private_key.pem

nodejs code
var fs = require("fs");
const http = require("http");
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

//create a server object:

var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

var private_key = fs.readFileSync("./private_key.pem");
var header = {
  kid: "bdef4554463d8078be9af1d9de55"
};

var payload = {
  iss: "a57bb14a44455e98800d6a513953fc0",
  sub: "a57bb14a445541e98800d6a513953fc0",
  aud: "https://c2performdev.talkdeskid.com/oauth/token",
  jti: uuidv4(),
  exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 300,
  iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
};

token = jwt.sign(payload, private_key, { header: header, algorithm: "ES256" });

console.log(token);

i am receiving this error
Error: secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using ES256
    at Object.module.exports [as sign] (/home//node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:130:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47




ES256 is ECDSA using P-256 (aka secp256r1) and SHA-256. You are using (a key for) curve secp384r1 (aka P-384). So either you change the curve to secp256r1 or you change the algorithm to ES384 (with SHA-384).
